# Android on Samsung Jet S8003?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung

I have recently got the urge to install and test different devices on uncommon OS markets.

I have discovered that I still have an old Samsung Jet S8003, and would like to install Android Gingerbread on the device. First and foremost, is it possible and would it be able to operate fine without bugs?

Second, could I install a later version of the Android OS like Jellybean or Kit-Kat?

I have tried [JetDroid](http://jetdroid.webs.com/) but have failed as the OS loads up in ssh and then it says that it cant load from ext2.

Comment: That is the JetDroid part of the question that i mentioned.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions from [here](http://jetdroid.webs.com/)?

Comment: That would be a confirmed.

Comment: And are you quite sure you formatted the SD Card correctly as per instructions in the "Using GParted" section? Specifically - you've created 2 partitions, first formatted as FAT32, and second (~1.5GB in size) as Ext3?

Comment: Some comments on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjeRIxV8GI0) seem to have had success in installing on Jet S8003. They mention that SD Card must be SDHC.  Perhaps that is your issue also?

Comment: I have found the error guys.
If you unpack the zip file JetDroid the files needs to go in the data folder the mobile makes when you boot it for the first time.

Comment: Can you post your answer as a separate Answer, and mark it as Accepted 2 days later? :)